# Get value of a hidden column

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with columns `ID,Name` and a `HyperLinkButton` on each row. My `ID` column is hidden by the property `Visibility="Collapsed"`. On HyperLinkButton's `Click` event I am accessing my columns value but I am unable to access the column when it is hidden i.e it returns null. Its only accessible when I make it `Visible`. Is there any solution to this problem?

XAML for DataGrid:

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Height="163"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Name="ProductGrid">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ID"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=ProductID, Mode=OneWay}"
                                Header="ID"
                                IsReadOnly="True"
                                Width="50"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Name"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}"
                                Header="Name"
                                IsReadOnly="True"
                                Width="340" />
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="">
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="gridTemplate">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <HyperlinkButton Content="Details"
                                         Tag="Hyperlinkbutton"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                         Click="OnGetDetailsClick"
                                         Width="100" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
```

HyperLink's click event:

```
var selectedGridRow = DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement(sender as FrameworkElement);
TextBlock txtblkID = (TextBlock)ProductGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(selectedGridRow);
p.ID = Int32.Parse(txtblkID.Text);
```

Comment: Can you the `HyperLinkButton` XAMl code too?

Comment: @user2946329 Added XAMl code for the DataGrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get hold of the DataContext of the selected row and get the value from there. Replace the DataSourceType cast with your model.

```
var selectedGridRow = DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement(sender as FrameworkElement);
p.ID = ((DataSourceType)selectedGridRow.DataContext).ProductID;
```

Comment: I added this line `p.ID = ((DataSourceType)selectedGridRow.DataContext).ProductID;` and got error `The type or namespace name DataSourceType could not be found`

Comment: Yes, as I said in the comment, I don't know what your data model is called, you have to replace that with whatever type you are using for your grid data source.

Comment: How? Currently I am binding the Grid with `GetProductsCompletedEventArgs e.Result` property 
`PagedCollectionView pagingCollection = new PagedCollectionView(e.Result);`
`ProductGrid.ItemsSource = pagingCollection;`

Comment: You are binding your ID column to a field called `ProductId`. Where is this product Id defined?

Comment: In a class `Product`

Comment: Okay, in that case you will use `p.ID = ((Product)selectedGridRow.DataContext).ProductID;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101254/discussion-between-jvanrhyn-and-huma-ali).